# one time connection MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have Several PHP files and each file need a Mysql connection. Then I have a common file connect.php with mysql basic database queries and I have added this files in Header.php.

But concern is that each time connect.php establishing a connection to DB (Because this is included in Header). That will be harmful MySql Server, My Application is large and approx. 200 tables in it with 200 thousand entries. I want to DB connection through php.ini , Means once I configure php.ini then no need to add mysql_connect() query any where in code. Only one setting in php.ini. Please explain the steps how to do that I am not familiar with php.ini

Comment: This wont matter. Unless you are using persistent connections, you will still create a new connection on every request. Persistent connections have some caveats to be aware of that can result in running out of available connections.

Comment: You can't connect to your database through php.ini. MySQL will be perfectly able handle the many requests.

Comment: now most of the time i am facing the issue with Table crash....

Comment: PDO::__construct , is help in this type of connections?

Comment: Tables crashing is unlikely to be caused by handling multiple connections.

Comment: how can i stop table crash issue ....?

Comment: By finding out *why* your tables are crashing. MyIsam tables crash rather easily.

Comment: So If i change table type to InnoDB, table crash issue will stop ?

Answer (score 0):

> My Application is large and approx. 200 tables in it with 200 thousand entries

That's not large. However the high number of tables is usually a good indicator that you trying to shard your data and breaking normalization.

> Means once I configure php.ini then no need to add mysql_connect() query any where in code

Is it really that hard to add mysql_connect(); ? You don't even need to explicitly set a username/password if they are set in your ini file or in an auto-prepended include file. Indeed if you wrap the db functions in your include file you can lazily connect:

```
<?php
ini_set('mysql.default_user', 'scott');
ini_set('mysql.default_password','pussycat');

$GLOBALS['my_db_handle']=false;

function wrap_mysql_connect()
{
   if (false===$GLOBALS['my_db_handle']) {
       $GLOBALS['my_db_handle']=mysql_connect();
       @mysql_select_db('my_preferred_db', $GLOBALS['my_db_handle']);
       @mysql_set_charset('utf8', $GLOBALS['my_db_handle']);
   }
   return $GLOBALS['my_db_handle'];
}

function wrap_mysql_query($sql)
{
   if (false===$GLOBALS['my_db_handle']) {
      wrap_mysql_connect();
   }
   if (false===$GLOBALS['my_db_handle']) {
      trigger_error(mysql_error());
      return false;
   }
   $result=mysql_query($sql, $GLOBALS['my_db_handle']);
   if (false === $result) {
      trigger_error(mysql_error());
      return false;
   }
   return result;
}
```

While opening database connections when they are not needed (and failing to explicitly close them when they are no longer required) does use up resources unnecessarily, the overhead is not that big - beware of premature optimization.

Comment: Remember to use `mysqli_*`.